# "if" statement not affecting the variable in the way requested

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to make the website check if cookieOk variable is true, then remove the cookie banner if it comes out as true, so that it can apply to all the pages on the site. For some reason, it removes the cookie banner without me clicking "OK".

I checked in Inspect and cookieOk is already set to true, which also explains why it's not showing the banner for me to click "OK".

How can I set the cookieOk variable to "true" only **after** I click "OK"?

I am also very new to the JavaScript language so please spare me if I have any errors in my code.

Here's the code if you want to test.

```js
function disappearObject1() {
  var remove = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");
  remove.remove();
  var cookieOk = true;
}

if (cookieOk = true) {
  var dis = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");
  dis.remove();
}
```

```css
.cookie-banner {
  background-color: #226da3;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #226da3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1200;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="gone" id="gone">
    <div class="cookie-banner" id="cookie-banner">
      <p class="p1"><b>This website uses cookies to improve user experience.</b></p>
      <button type="button" onclick="disappearObject1()" class="cookie-btn"><b>OK</b></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is a simple typo issue: `=` is assignment. `==` is equality testing with type coercion, `===` is strict equality testing. And note that you almost _always_ want `===`, not `==`. If you come to JS from most other programming languages, stop using `==` as soon as possible =)

Answer (score 1):

You are making an assignment rather than a comparison.

```js
if (cookieOk = true) {
```

should be

```js
if (cookieOk == true) {
```

With double or triple equal.

Comment: I think you mean *assignment

Comment: Questions caused by a typo such as this one should not be answered but commented instead. Typo caused issues are reason for closure and removal. As such, points awarded will be lost anyways.

Comment: @tacoshy Good to know for next time.